# postgres cursor unresolved reference in python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I wish to check if a record exists and then if it does i want to read the records in the other table. I am using the same cursor of the database that i created but it shows unresolved reference for the cursor inside the if block.
My code:

```
import psycopg2

conn=psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database='my_first_db', user='postgres', password='postgres')
curr= conn.cursor()
res=curr.execute("select EXISTS(select * from teachers where t_name='xoxo' AND pass='xoxo2020')")
if curr.fetchone()[0]==1 :
    {
        curr.execute("select * from students")
        result=curr.fetchall()
        for x in result:
            print(x)
        #print('Table exists')
    }
else:
    print("not found")
print(res)
curr.close()
conn.close()
```

the curr in the second line of if block shows the unresolved error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My familiarization with psycopg2 limited so you may have to adjust the following some. But in straight sql this can be accomplished is a single statement:

```
select * 
  from students
 where exists (select null 
                 from teachers
                where t_name = 'xoxo'
                  and password = 'xoxo2020'
              );
```

As best as I can determine this translates to psycopg2 as (subject ot above):

```
conn=psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database='my_first_db', user='postgres', password='postgres')
curr= conn.cursor()
curr.execute("select * from students where exists (select null from teachers where t_name='xoxo' and password='xoxo2020')")
if curr.rowcount > 0
    result=curr.fetchall()
    for x in result:
        print(x)
else:
    print("not found")

curr.close()
conn.close()
```

The main idea is when working with sql stop thinking in terms of  
   check A; If it exists then do B;  
But rather think in terms of  
  do B where A;

In other words let a single sql statement do **ALL the work**, including any checking needed.

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked by creating a function outside, for the working inside the if statement and called the function in the if block. and it works fine. Though any answers for the query are welcome.